# If we have $n+1$ linear equations in $n$ variables then does it means that the system has no solution or infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

Let us take an example where $a+b$=3, $a-b$=1, and $ab=2$. Solving the first two equations give the values of $a$ and $b$ as 2 and 1 respectively and putting these values into last equation yields an identity. So, in no way it means here that the system will have infinite solution. So, the proposition in the question is false.

But I found the proposition to be written in my Maths notes. So, I wanted to have your views on this. May be I've miswritten something in my notes. Am I right?

Comment: $ab =2$ is not a linear equation.

Comment: The propsition is indeed false, although your counterexample is faulty because $ab=2$ is not a ***linear*** equation. But you could replace it with, for example, $a+2b=4$ which is linear. Maybe you switched $n$ and $n+1$ in your notes? Maybe it was $n$ linear equations in $n+1$ variables?

Comment: Thank you @bof ...... if there were $n$ equations in $n+1$ variables then we can reduce the system to a linear equation in two variables and such an equation always have an infinite solutions (and not zero solutions) right?

Comment: Two linear equations in three variables: $$x+y+z=1$$ $$x+y+z=2$$